# java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to ******.class

Tags: lista

Estoy tratando de obtener cada uno de los objetos que conforman una Lista de objetos para que cuando itere sobre ellos valla añadiendolos a una base de datos.

El procedimiento que sigo es el suguiente:

1.Llamo a este metodo que me convierte un string Json a una lista de objetos.

```
    public List<Schedule> jsonStringToArray(String jsonString) throws IOException {
    return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(jsonString, /*new TypeReference<List<Schedule>>(){}*/ List.class);

    //return OBJECT_MAPPER.convertValue(schedules, new TypeReference<List<Schedule>>() {});
}
```

2. Itero y obtengo cada objeto para añadirlo en la base de datos

   ```
       for (int i = 0; i < schedules.getSchedulesList().size(); i++) {

       scheduleService.saveSchedule(schedules.getSchedulesList().get(i));
       System.out.println(schedules.getSchedulesList().get(i));
   }
   ```

El fallo me da en la linea del save y me dice lo siguiente:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to es.ticnor.trayecbus.model.Schedule

Creo que el error esta en el metodo jsonStringToArray, a la hora de hacer el return no estoy realizando bien el mapper de tal manera que lo convierta en un objeto Schedule. Lo que creo que esta haciedno es hacer en una especie de objeto auxiliar de tipo LinkedHashMap

Comment: has debugeado para ver que contiene getSchedulesList ?? es evidente que el método schedules.getSchedulesList().get(i) te está devolviendo un linkedhashmap en vez de un solo schedule

Comment: Si hago un System.out.print a getSchedulesList() me devuelve lo siguiente: [{id=3318, name=Lunes, days=[2018-05-04, 2018-05-10]}, {id=3319, name=Martes, days=[2018-05-05, 2018-05-11]}]